# error postgresql con django

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, postgresql

error:

```
manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\djangopg\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 92, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 275, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\Programacion\programacionWeb\postgresql_django\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Lo único que he tocado en el proyecto es esto:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'pruebas',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'pruebas',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Que comando corriste? estás seguro que la base de datos existe? puedes poner el error completo? me parece que falta una parte, Estas seguro que ese es el usuario y el password?

Comment: Esta puesto el error completo.

Comment: El comando fue manage.py makemigrations, te aparece al principio del error

Comment: Si, ese es el usuario y la contraseña correctas.

Comment: a mi también me apareció ese error, pero el problema en mi caso era que el password no estaba bien, una vez corregí el password funciono bien.

Answer (score 1):

El comando es

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

y no olvides tener activo el virtual
Si es la primera vez que corres las migraciones, antes de ejecutar makemigrations ejecuta el comando:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Para que se generen las tablas por defecto de Django

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/79358)

Comment: No es una crítica, puede que el error sea por alguna de estas razones

Comment: ¿Acaso no es lo que publicó en la pregunta en la primera línea?

Comment: Mariano, vuelve a leer y encuentra la diferencia ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente no dices que versión de Python y Django usas, esta información es importante, tampoco mencionas si tienes instalado el sistema gestor de base de datos PostgreSQL

> Django es compatible con PostgreSQL 9.3 y superior. Se requiere psycopg2 2.5.4 o superior, aunque se recomienda la versión más reciente.

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

**django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2** según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#engine)
 debería ser **django.db.backends.postgresql**

**Documentación settings.py ENGINES (bases de datos):** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#engine

Answer (score 0):

Puede que no hayas creado la base de datos o escribiste mal el nombre de ella.

De no ser el caso, ejecuta los comandos:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```